# Add a letter between a pair of duplicated letters C#

Tags: c#, duplicates

I want to add an "X" between a pair of duplicated letters, for example if it is "SSM" i want it to be "SX" and "SM", this is what i have did, but it doesn't add the 'X', how can i fix it?
len is "SSM"

```
 for (int i = 0; i < len.Length - 1; i++)
            {

            if (len[i] == len[i + 1])
            {
                Nlen += 'X';
            }
        }
```

Stringbuilders will require me to change a lot in my code, how can i solve them without using stringbuilders?

Comment: use a stringbuilder. strings are immutable.

Comment: You DO NOT want to use strings for this, as I can induce a CPU starvation attack if I was to use a string of 500+ "A"s in a row.  Wrap it in a method, and use StringBuilder

Comment: @DanielA.White replacing fix text for duplicate i honestly don't think about `StringBuilder` first, i think regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach:

```
var chars = input.ToList();
for (var index = input.Length - 1; index > 0; index--)
{
    if (chars[index] == chars[index - 1])
        chars.Insert(index, 'X');
}
return new string(chars.ToArray());
```

SSM => SXSM
SSSM => SXSXSM

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my VS editor here but something akin to this:

```
char lastChar = '';
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(char c in len)
{
  if (c == lastChar) { sb.Append('X') }
  sb.Append(c);
  lastChar = c;
}

return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Of course, you get some interesting items where you have "XX" in your string, which would become "XXX"

Answer (score 0):

This will give you SXSM, I wasn't sure from your question if you wanted them grouped in pairs, ie (SX, SM) or just insert the X.

```
        string len = "SSM";
        StringBuilder Nlen = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < len.Length; i++)
        {

            if ((i+1) < len.Length && len[i] == len[i + 1])
            {
                Nlen.Append(len[i]);
                Nlen.Append('X');
            }
            else
            {
                Nlen.Append(len[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Nlen` doesn’t take into account the current character in the array:

```
Nlen += len[i] + ‘X’
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex substitution

```cs
var len = "SSM";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(len, @"([a-z,A-Z])\1", @"$1X$1");
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

The output in this case is "SXSM"

Regex explanation

- `([a-z,A-Z])` matches any character a-z or A-Z and stores in capture group 1
- `\1` back reference to capture group 1. If the previous match was "S", then for it to be a full match the next character would have to be a "S"
- `$1X$1` Substitution string. Takes the capture group 1 like in our example the letter "S" and puts an "X" between the two S's